# Calculating pooled estimates after manipulating datasets

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, pooling, mice

After I imputed two datasets, the two datasets are synthesized via statistical matching. With the synthesized data, I tried to pool estimates but got errors as below.

```
data1_mice_rf <- mice(data1, maxit = 1, m = 50, method="rf", seed = 500)
data2_mice_rf <- mice(data2, maxit = 1, m = 50, method="rf", seed = 500)
group.v <- c("public","gender")
X.mtc <- c("age", "income")
out.nnd <- NND.hotdeck(data.rec=data1, data.don=data2,
    match.vars=X.mtc, don.class=group.v, dist.fun = "Gower")
fA.nnd <- create.fused(data.rec=data1, data.don=data2, mtc.ids=out.nnd$mtc.ids, z.vars="happy_factor")
testmodel <- with(fA.nnd, lm(depression ~ dl_factor))
summary(pool(testmodel))

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 
'summary': No tidy method for objects of class qr
In addition: Warning messages:

1: In get.dfcom(object, dfcom) : Infinite sample size assumed.

2: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.

See help("Deprecated")
```

**I guess** the problem is that the original imputed datasets are not used for pooled estimates. Instead, one more step was used (i.e., statistical matching), and pooled estimates are not computed with the new data.
I was wondering if there are any ways to solve it or if there is an easy way to pool the 50 estimates with certain codes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you fit linear regression on both out.nnd and fA.nnd? I'm not sure `pool()` can help you afterwards, but manually pooling them with `pool.scalar()` would do the trick.